# Passing data from parent component to child component in angular

Tags: html, arrays, angular, typescript

In here i want to put `this.formattedBookingPrice, this.formattedCheckingPrice` values in to `value` array and pass them to child component not the static values.But since it's coming inside `subscribe` method i couldn't access them.Can i get a solution for this?

This is my parent component.

```
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit{
  lineChart = ['line_chart1', 'line_chart2', 'line_chart3', 'line_chart4', 'line_chart5'];
  value = [ this.formattedBookingPrice,  this.formattedCheckingPrice, '09.9M'];
  names = [  'Bookings', 'Checkins', 'Modifications', 'Revenue' ];
  numberUtil = new NumberUtil();
  bookingInfo = [];
  checkingInfo = [];

   ngOnInit() {
    this.getBookingInfo();
    this.getCheckingInfo();
  }

   getBookingInfo() {

      this.getTxnInfo('BOOKING').subscribe(
        bookings => {
          this.bookingInfo = bookings.responseObj.txnValues;
           this.bookingTtcSum = checkings.responseObj.ttcSum;
          this.formattedBookingPrice = numberUtil.formatPriceDefault(this.bookingTtcSum, ' M ').substring(2);
          console.log(this.bookingInfo);
      });
  }

  getCheckingInfo() {

  this.getTxnInfo('CHECKIN').subscribe(
    checkings => {
      this.checkingInfo = checkings.responseObj.txnValues;
      this.checkingTtcSum = checkings.responseObj.ttcSum;
        this.formattedCheckingPrice = this.numberUtil.formatPriceDefault(this.checkingTtcSum, ' M ').substring(2);
    });
  }

}
```

This is html.

```
<app-chips  [lineChart]="lineChart[0]" [value] = "value[0]" [name] = "names[0]" [bookingInfo] = "bookingInfo"></app-chips>
<app-chips  [lineChart]="lineChart[1]" [value] = "value[1]" [name] = "names[1]" [checkingInfo] = "checkingInfo"></app-chips>
```

This is my child component.

```
export class ChipsComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {
@Input('lineChart') lineChart: string;
  @Input('value') value: string;
  @Input('name') name: string;
  @Input() bookingInfo = [];
  @Input()  checkingInfo = [];

}
```

This is child component html.

```
<div class="l-content-wrapper c-summary-chip oh" >
  <div class="c-summary-chip__value">{{value}}</div>
  <div class="c-summary-chip__txt">{{name}}</div>
  <div id= "{{lineChart}}" class="c-summary-chip__graph ">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

re-assign the value array in subscribe and implement `changeDetectionStrategy`(call `this.ref.detectChanges()` after assignment) now check in `ngOnChanges()` method of child component

check this following example

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/angular-change-detection-strategy

it explains your requirement with details and code examples

Comment: changeDetectionStrategy i need to implement in  child component

Comment: changeDetectionStrategy in parent component and add `ngonchanges()` in child

Comment: `ngonchanges()` already i have used in my child compont.I 'l add  `changeDetectionStrategy`

Comment: calling detectChanges() in parent will call ngOnchanges() in child with change in value array

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add into **value[ ]** in the `subscribe()`. Like shown below.

```
   getBookingInfo() {

      this.getTxnInfo('BOOKING').subscribe(
        bookings => {
          this.bookingInfo = bookings.responseObj.txnValues;
           this.bookingTtcSum = checkings.responseObj.ttcSum;
          this.formattedBookingPrice = numberUtil.formatPriceDefault(this.bookingTtcSum, ' M ').substring(2);
          console.log(this.bookingInfo);
          this.value.push(formattedBookingPrice);
      });
  }



  getCheckingInfo() {

  this.getTxnInfo('CHECKIN').subscribe(
    checkings => {
      this.checkingInfo = checkings.responseObj.txnValues;
      this.checkingTtcSum = checkings.responseObj.ttcSum;
        this.formattedCheckingPrice = this.numberUtil.formatPriceDefault(this.checkingTtcSum, ' M ').substring(2);
    });

     this.value.push(this.formattedCheckingPrice);
  }
```

Comment: Then how do i know which value is in which index.

Comment: @Mandara how you were identifying earlier when it was hard coded. If this is case i would suggest to insert `{key, value}` pair in `value[ ]` for unique identification.

Comment: value = [ '9.9M',  '9M', '09.9M']; like this